# passing array of double from vb to c++ dll

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net

I try to pass an array of doubles from VB to C++ (and hopefully in the end the other way around).

I have looked at several pages that seems to indicate a method that looks a bit like the following (but with more parameters being passed to myfun in mydll.cpp):
in C++ (mydll.cpp)

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myfun(LPSAFEARRAY FAR arrayCppIn)
{
  double *pArray;
  pArray = (double*)((*arrayCppIn)->pvData);
  double testvar = pArray[0]
}
```

this together with VB code (vbtestcppdll):

```
Public Declare Function myfun Lib "mydll.dll" (ByRef arrVBout() As Double) As Integer

Dim result As Integer
Dim testarr = New Double {1.1, 2.5, 6}
result = myfun(testarr)
```

In debug mode (MSVS2013), as soon as I reach teh `double testvar = pArray[0]` I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AxxessViolationException' occurded in vbtestcppdll.exe"
Further down it says that "This is often an indication that memory is corrupt". The cDims,cbElements, cElements, of the PLSAFEARRAY seem all to be corrupt.

Scalars (integer and double) all go through as they should.

Anyone's got any ideas??

(I got help from :
http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Interfacing_Visual_Basic_And_C.shtml)

Comment: pArray = (double*)((*arrayCppIn)->pvData);

Do you actually want the double indirection to arrayCppIn or should that be      pArray = (double*)((*arrayCppIn).pvData); or pArray = (double*)(arrayCppIn->pvData); I don't have any of the type documentation in front of me but it's a guess. You might be able to use the debugger at this line to determine exactly what it is you are expecting to see.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pArray = (double*)(arrayCppIn->pvData);`. Your example shouldn't even be compilable.

Comment: Nope, it needs all the *s, otherwise it won't compile. AFAIU the LPSAFEARRAY is a pointer to SAFEARRAY

Comment: `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)>` required so the pinvoke marshaller knows it needs to create a safe array and not just pass a pointer to the first array element.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant, that solved it!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hans Passant's comment, the answer is to declare the function in VB as

```
Public Declare Function myfun Lib "mydll.dll" (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)> ByRef arrVBout() As Double) As Integer
```